# How can I rotate a plot x axis and y axis using pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = [0, 0.02, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12, 0.16, 0.2]
y1 = [0.0005, 0.052, 0.0905, 0.1675, 0.2485, 0.3225, 0.4035]

plt.scatter(x1, y1)
plt.title("y-x scatter")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

It works fun as follows:
[image]

but what my goal is an image like this:

[image]

How can I rotate the Image like this using matplotlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot rotate the toolbar on the plot without completely rewriting it. That seems a bit too much work so I'll leave that out.

Apart from that there is no big problem rotating all the elements in the plot and exchanging the role of x and y axis. Specifically,

- all texts can get a `rotation` argument.
- The data can simply be exchanged, i.e. `scatter(y,x)`.
- The axis can be inverted, `ax.invert_xaxis()`
- The location of the ticks can be set to the right side `ax.yaxis.tick_right()`
- The "title" can be emulated with a usual text element.

Compelte code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [0, 0.02, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12, 0.16, 0.2]
y1 = [0.0005, 0.052, 0.0905, 0.1675, 0.2485, 0.3225, 0.4035]

fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"][::-1])
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.875, top=0.9,bottom=0.125)

ax.scatter(y1, x1)

ax.set_ylabel("x", rotation=90)
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
ax.set_xlabel("y", rotation=180)
ax.invert_xaxis()

plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90, va="top", ha="center")
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=90, va="center", ha="left")

ax.text(-0.05,0.5,"y-x scatter", ha="center", va="center",
        transform=ax.transAxes, rotation=90)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about having negative numbers on the scale you can simply: `plt.scatter([-y for y in y1], x1)`

You'll also need to change the labels on the axes, but that would plot x on the vertical axis and y on horizontal, negative values to go from right to left.

If on the other hand you want to rotate the image, you can save it and rotate to file, rotate with another tool and read that file.