# Is it possible make vertical charts in Power BI?

Tags: charts, powerbi

I would like to have time or distance on the y-axis and values on the x-axis and make vertical charts not horizontal ones. For example, I would like time on the y-axis to start a 0 hours and continue all the way down to 13 hours. I would like to see values ranging from 1-5 on the x-axis. Basically, I would like a flipped or transposed line chart. I would also like to do the same thing with a bar chart. Is this possible in Power BI?

Vertical Line Chart:

[image: Vertical Line Chart]

Multiple Bar Charts:

[image: Multiple Bar Charts]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a couple ways to accomplish this:

1. Download the [multiple axes chart](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA200000183?tab=Overview) Power BI add-on from the Microsoft app store.
2. Make the visualization in Python or R from the Power BI visualization ribbon. For example, you could use Python and the Matplotlib library. In Matplotlib you can [invert the axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49517286/how-can-i-rotate-a-plot-x-axis-and-y-axis-using-pyplot) to make the preferred chart.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have the same need and had found a tool that allow me to perform vertical charts. Take a look on [Multiple Vertical Line Chart](https://pbivizedit.com/gallery/vertical-line-chart)

[image: Vertical line chart for well logs (petrophysics)]

Some other alternatives are:

- [Create visuals using python scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-visuals)
- [Develop custom visuals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/environment-setup)